# How to verify that my link title attribute has specified value?

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have a link somewhere on my page, let say like this

```
<a href="http://example.com" title="my title message">my link label</a>
```

How to verify, that my link title attribute has 'my title message' value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assertattribute command use to verify it, please check this code.

```
assertattribute  | title = my title message@href | http://example.com
assertattribute  | link=my link label@href       | http://example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

From Selenium IDE use this:

```
command         | target                   | value
-------------------------------------------------------------
assertAttribute | link=my link label@title | my title message
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

command: verifyTitle

target: my title message

this command will compare the actual page title with the text given in the command target if both is same no error will show other wise error will display

Thank You...

Comment: thx for you're response, but my question is not about <title>value</title> tag.