# How can I verify the class of an element in the first row using selenium ide?

Tags: selenium, ui-testing

If I have a table with the below structure, how can I verify if the first i-frame has a class of "fa-star" using selenium IDE?

```
<thead></thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="odd" role="row">
    <td class="text-center noteworthy-select sorting_1">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to user `assertAttribute` to order to verify the value of an attribute.

with `xpath`

```
assertAttribute| xpath=//tr[@class='odd']/td/i@class|fa fa-start
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093639/how-to-verify-that-my-link-title-attribute-has-specified-value) explanation

**Similar test case**

[image]